# Gmail Annotations tracking

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

I have a question if it is possible to track the played annotations. So if I can see somewhere, which of my customers/recipients were played the codes or carousels and which not.
At the moment I can only see which customers use Gmail. I would like to be able to track more. Do you have any tips?
Thanks for the answer. Anna